# C++ noise interpolation issue

Tags: c++

I am attempting to generate noise similar to perlin or value noise.

I am using stb_image_write library from [here](https://github.com/nothings/stb) to write to image file (i write to disk as hdr and converted to png with GIMP to post on here).

This code requires C++ 20 because I am using std::lerp();

Because I am generating a linear gradient as testing I am expecting a linear gradient as output.

I know there are more steps to generating the desired noise but, this is where I'm having issues.

```
#include <cmath>

template <size_t size>
void noise(float seed[size][size], float output[size][size], size_t octave);

int main()
{
    // generate test gradient
    float seedNoise[64][64] = {};
    for ( size_t x = 0; x < 64; x++ )
    {
        for ( size_t y = 0; y < 64; y++ )
        {
            seedNoise[x][y] = ((((float)x) / 64.0f + ((float)y / 64.0f)) / 2.0f);
        }
    }

    float _map[64][64] = { 0 };
    noise<64>(seedNoise, _map, 4);


}

template <size_t size>
void noise(float seed[size][size], float output[size][size], size_t octave)
{
    size_t step = size / octave;   // went back to this
    // size_t step = (size - 1) / octave;  // took this back out

    for ( size_t x = 0; x <= size - step; x += step )
    {
        for ( size_t y = 0; y <= size - step; y += step )
        {   // each octave

            // extract values at corners octave from seed
            float a = seed[x][y];
            float b = seed[x + (step - 1)][y];    // changed this
            float c = seed[x][y + (step - 1)];    // this
            float d = seed[x + (step - 1)][y + (step - 1)]; // and this

            for ( size_t u = 0; u < step; u++ )
            {
                float uStep = ((float)u) / ((float)step);   // calculate x step
                for ( size_t v = 0; v < step; v++ )
                {   // each element in each octave
                    float vStep = ((float)v) / ((float)step);   // calculate y step

                    float x1 = std::lerp(a, b, uStep);  // interpolate top edge
                    float x2 = std::lerp(c, d, uStep);  // interpolate bottom edge
                    float y1 = std::lerp(a, c, vStep);  // interpolate left edge
                    float y2 = std::lerp(b, d, vStep);  // interpolate right edge

                    float x3 = std::lerp(x1, x2, vStep);    // interpolate between top and bottom edges
                    float y3 = std::lerp(y1, y2, uStep);    // interpolate between left and right edges

                    float odat = (x3 + y3) / 2;     // average top/bottom and left/right interpolations

                    output[x + u][y + v] = odat;

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[Source gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LubZs.png) I think this should be similar to what the output should be.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9132.png) As you can see here the right and bottom of the output is all messed up.

[new output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjVhE.png)

Comment: Could you explain exactly what is wrong with your new output?

Comment: @GaryNLOL it was the right most and bottom most 4 pixels, i have fully functioning code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're accessing the imago outside it's boundaries.
X and y can go up to 60 in the loops:

`for ( size_t x = 0; x <= size - step; x += step )`

And the you are accessing position `y+step` and `x+step`, which gives 64.

Comment: i edited the post to show what  i changed and how it affected the output im not sure what but the last octave number of row and columns are black while the rest of the image is 100% correct now, is there somewhere else i should have made a change

Comment: Rather than change step and use x+step as the array indeksi, limit the array indeksi to size-1. Like int nextx = x+step; if (next > size-1)....

Comment: thank you i really appreciate your help, an array bounds error makes me feel really dumb because ive been programming for almost 20 years, lol